# JS - как изменить атрибут required

Tags: javascript

Когда нам надо поменять стиль мы пишем:

```
block.style.width =
```

Когда тип то пишем

```
block.type.width =
```

А как работать с `required`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может так?

```
document.getElementById("id").required = true;
```

Comment: да, всё верно, спасибо

Comment: Если ответ решил вашу проблему, то пожалуйста, примите его.

Comment: Обязательно, но злобный стак говорит что я ответ могу принять только через 9 минут ))))

Answer (score 1):

```js
element.setAttribute("required", "");    //устанавливаем required через метод
element.required = true;                 //устанавливаем required через свойство

element.removeAttribute("required");     //убираем required через метод
element.required = false;                //убираем required через свойство

if (edName.hasAttribute("required")) { }  //проверяем required через метод
if (edName.required) { }                 //проверяем required через свойство
```

Еще немного интересного на эту тему можно узнать на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770369)